TradingView: Did intraday high occur before intraday low?
in my PineScript I would like to plot (per day - including the current trading session), if the intraday high occured before the intraday low (or vice versa).

You can use the varip keyword to keep track of the intra-bar actions. Then just update your intra-day high and low. You can use the time built-in variable to see when that event took place and then later compare those times to see which one took place first.
//@version=5

indicator(title="bar color", overlay=true)

is_new_day = timeframe.change("D")

varip day_high = high
varip day_high_time = time

varip day_low = low
varip day_low_time = time

if (is_new_day)                 // Reset variables if it is a new day
    day_high := high
    day_high_time := time

    day_low := low
    day_low_time := time
else
    if (high > day_high)        // New high
        day_high := high
        day_high_time := time

    if (low < day_low)          // New low
        day_low := low
        day_low_time := time

// Compare day_high_time and day_low_time
// Plot whatever you want

